# get value of an alias in bash

Tags: linux, bash, alias, tcsh

I recently switched from tcsh to bash, and I'm used to being able to do things like `` sudo `alias netstat` `` but since `alias` gives `name=value` in bash, I can't do this anymore.  Is there an equivalent in bash, so I don't have to do `` sudo `alias netstat | sed -r "s/.*='(.*)'/\1/"` ``?

Comment: Wrap it in a function and add it to `.bashrc`. Problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to have *bash* expand aliases after `sudo`. You do not need to do it the exact same way; in fact, there is a far more convenient way in bash – add an alias for `sudo` that ends with a space...

```
alias sudo="sudo "
```

...and `sudo netstat` will be expanded automatically.

Comment: excellent, and `sudo \netstat` won't expand netstat's alias!

Answer (score 11):

Bash stores its list of aliases in the associative array `BASH_ALIASES`. The equivalent of `` sudo `alias netstat` `` is then `sudo ${BASH_ALIASES[netstat]}`. However, I would suggest the following instead, which works with builtin shell commands and deals correctly with quoting:

```
sudo bash -c "${BASH_ALIASES[netstat]}"
```

There's still a lot that won't work with this, like e.g. nested aliases.